# Android studio 3.1 failed to load aapt when running emulator

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.1

The project **builds** and **syncs** successfully but when running the project on emulator(my phone), i get the error: **Failed to execute aapt**, and also  **Caused by:java.util.NoSuchElementException**.

In gradle properties is **android.enableAapt2 = false**

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for
>   task ':app:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug'.    at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
>     at

Here is the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sran.dzepniprofesor"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
}
```

Comment: post your full logcat.

Comment: okay I edited and posted

Comment: Post you gradle file, and manifest

Comment: Have you checked your xml files? It seems to be related to your xml files + the "old" api version of your emulator.

Comment: I am using my phone for emulator and his api is 23

Answer (score 0):

Go to preferences(settings) : click on Build,Execution,Deployment .....then select : Instant Run ......and uncheck its topmost checkbox (i.e Disable Instant Run)